# Move row based on cell selection

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that moves the whole row to a different tab and deletes it from the tab it was moved based on a "list" selection.

The script is the following:

```
    // Script Move & Delete
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Needed
  // target sheet of move to named Acquired
  // test column with yes/no is col 4 or D
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  // In Review Trigger
  if(s.getName() == "Applied" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == "In Review") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("In Review");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
  // In Review Trigger
  else if(s.getName() == "Applied" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == "Failed") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Failed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
```

So for example, if the row on Tab "Applied" and value of cell on column 1 = In Review then the row is moved to tab "In Review" but if the value of cell on column one = to Failed then row is moved to tab Failed.

That part works like charm and I know having multiple tabs will have a lot of else ifs, I'm not much of a dev, so I was wondering how can I do to move the row if the status (Column 1) is changed to Applied is moved to tab one or failed tab if value is changed to failed?

Basically, move the rows between tabs based on value of column one of each row/tab.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: Thank you @Aerials with my current script, I can only move rows from tab 1 (Applied) to any of the other tabs but not from others tabs. I think I can do it with if /else if but it would be a really big script but that's what my current skills can accomplish so I figure there must be a simple way.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('entry');
  const s = e.range.getSheet();
  if (s.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.value) {
    //e.source.toast('cond')
    const names = ['Sheet2', 'Sheet3'];
    let idx = names.indexOf(e.value);
    if (~idx) {
      //e.source.toast('sheet');
      let tsh = e.source.getSheetByName(names[idx]);
      let tgt = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, s.getLastColumn()).moveTo(tgt);
      s.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
    }
  }
}
```

I made some name changes to make it easier for me to debug so look it over to make sure all of the sheet names are right for your needs.

Comment: It looks like this one would be the way to go, however, I wanted to ask if the values on const names should match for example, In Review on cell, should match the tab name?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes they must match the sheet name so that this can work properly:`let targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(names[idx]);`

Comment: Hey @MetaMan, thank you, I tested this but it didn't work.

The first tab is Applied, to the first column, they have the Applied value, from a list, I selected In Review but they were not moved, I also changed the name to InReview on the tab and the value the select is getting from a range, I also tested typing the InReview on the cell but didn't move it.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you require more complex functionality in moving rows, take a look at the [moveRowsFromSpreadsheetToSpreadsheet_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/39992635?msgid=40432488) script. It is unfortunately too long to quote here directly.