# Move Rows based on matches between 3 columns

Tags: google-apps-script

My goal is to compare the entries', from the *Data* tab, First Name, Last Name, and Date of Birth to the same columns on another tab named *Completed* and erase the matching rows from the *Data* tab.

Marking a checkbox on another tab *New Cases* should find the row on *Data*, Move that row to *Completed*, and clear the checkbox on *New Cases*.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sVVzW4Ga6XzYrGS-7AqwdMCqeL1-IxzRVSHG2FxMCog/edit?usp=sharing

I found a couple scripts that approached what I wanted, and I copied them into the sheet, but I don't have the expertise to get either ([Move row based on cell selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67204527/move-row-based-on-cell-selection)) or (https://support.google.com/docs/thread/39992635?msgid=40432488) to accomplish the solution.

I was able to get something like this to work, but it only worked once, and I was only able to get it to move a row from (New Cases) to (Completed).

```
function onEdit(event) {
// assumes source data in sheet named New Cases
// target sheet of move to named     Completed
// getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to colu 21 or V
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

if(s.getName() == "New Cases" && r.getColumn() == 21 && r.getValue() == true) {
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
s.deleteRow(row);
}
}
```

Edit: I'm trying to get any row from "Data" where Columns C, D, AND E match any row on "Completed" to automatically delete off of the "Data" sheet.

Then, when the checkbox on "New Cases" is checked in column V, it moves the matching row from "Data" to "Completed" and unchecks the box on "New Cases" so it's ready for the next entry.

Comment: What three columns do you wish to match and how should they match with each other or some other value?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I added additional info.

Comment: i edit you question a little.  I understand the first paragraph but still misunderstand the second.  It almost sounds like another process.  Can you add more detail please.

Comment: It is a separate process, but I can figure it out once the first part is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Select checkbox on New Cases Find row on Data move Data row to Completed

Delete row on Data and reset checkbox on new cases.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const nsh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (nsh.getName() == "New Cases" && e.range.columnStart == 22 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value() == "TRUE") {
    const nrg = nsh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, nsh.getLastColumn());
    const nvs = nrg.getValues().flat();//row
    const dsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Data");
    const dvs = dsh.getRange(2, 1, dsh.getLastRow() - 1, dsh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    const csh = e.source.getSheetByName("Completed");
    const tgt = csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    for (let i = 0; i < dvs.length; i++) {
      if (dvs[i][2] == nvs[2] && dvs[i][3] == nvs[3] && dvs[i][4] == nvs[4]) {
        let drg = dsh.getRange(i + 1, 1, 1, dsh.getLastColumn());
        drg.copyTo(tgt);
        dsh.deleteRow(i + 1);
        break;
      }
    }
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");//reset the checkbox
    //e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date());//you should consider doing this so that you know that it has been moved.  The way it setup now it would put the timestamp in column W
  }
}
```